# Why is wlan0 gone?

Tags: debian, wifi, networkmanager, bunsenlabs

I have this machine under BunsenLabs Hydrogen (Debian Jessie pre configured for Openbox) for ~6 month. Was pleased with it and everything worked fine.

About 2 week ago, a new linux-firmware-amd64 version came out, and I started to have trouble with wifi after making the PC sleep/hibernate.

However, since yesterday, I have no wifi. At all.

My first thought was that `iwlwifi` must have gone corrupt or something, so I reinstalled it, reboot and... nothing.

After looking around a bit, I see that wlan0 just stopped existing:

```
drakasan@bld219:~$ lspci | grep Network
02:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 7265 (rev 61)
drakasan@bld219:~$ rfkill list
4: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
drakasan@bld219:~$ iwconfig 
eth0      no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.
```

Now I m as stuck as I am baffled. How can wlan0 just disappear like that? I would have expected that tw week ago with the kernel upgrade, but not two week later. Also, booting from the old kernel doesn't work either.

Kernel: 4.9.0-0.bpo.3-amd64, can boot on 4.9.0-0.bpo.2-amd64.

Comment: Look at output of `dmesg` after boot, see if it contains messages/errors for `iwlwifi` etc. If there's nothing at all, try `sudo modprobe iwlwifi`, look again. If you can't make sense of it, put of all it in a pastebin (no grep/excerpts, please), edit question with link. Maybe the new firmware is buggy, maybe you pulled in some dependencies that broke stuff, maybe something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up resolving the problem by installing the `jessie-backports` version of `firmware-iwlwifi`:

```
sudo apt install -t jessie-backports firmware-iwlwifi
```